# MSBuild.exe has stopped cmake error

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild, cmake, windows-10, cmake-gui

I was able to compile zlib yesterday with CMake but the only possible change was installing Windows 10 SDK 10.0.14393.33 and now that I configure it with the same choice (Visual Studio 14 2015 win64) I get the following error:
[image]

[image]

Any idea what could have gone wrong and how to fix it?

```
The C compiler identification is unknown
CMake Error: Could not find cmake module file: C:/Users/mona/playing-for-data/renderdoc/renderdoc/3rdparty/zlib/build /CMakeFiles/3.7.1/CMakeCCompiler.cmake
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:4 (project):
  No CMAKE_C_COMPILER could be found.


Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "C:/Users/mona/playing-for-data/renderdoc/renderdoc/3rdparty/zlib/build /CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "C:/Users/mona/playing-for-data/renderdoc/renderdoc/3rdparty/zlib/build /CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
```

Comment: In the path to missed module file `C:/Users/mona/playing-for-data/renderdoc/renderdoc/3rdparty/zlib/build /CMakeFiles/3.7.1/CMakeCCompiler.cmake` there is a space after the 'build' component. Probably, it is a reason of such fault.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well, really weird but turns out you have to run CMake with right clicking on the executable and running it as admin. I am not sure if this is the correct solution but now it is working!!!

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem (running CMake in admin mode does change the search `PATH` environment it runs in).

This problem is specific to `msbuild` and also does occur only in newer versions of CMake because the default build program was changed from `devenv` to `msbuild`.

What did help in my case was to put the following code in my VS toolchain file:

```
if (CMAKE_VS_DEVENV_COMMAND)
    set(CMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM "${CMAKE_VS_DEVENV_COMMAND}" CACHE INTERNAL "")
endif()
```