# Adding a CMake project to a Visual Studio solution

Tags: c++, visual-studio, cmake

I am working on a Visual Studio 2013 project and would like to link it to a library that uses CMake to generate a build configuration. For example:

```
project
|-> src
    |-> project.sln
|-> dep
    |-> library
        |-> src
            |-> CMakeLists.txt
```

Is there a way to configure, build, and link my library to my project when I build the project in Visual Studio?

I would like to eventually make the whole project a CMake project and generate a comprehensive Visual Studio solution, but it is currently quite large and complicated. With limited time, I'm wondering what my best option is. Is there a clean way to do this with VS Custom Build commands?

Answer (score 4):

Here is most simplified version of CMake's configuration and build steps.

Just create a Configuration Type / Utility project in the same folder as your `CMakeLists.txt` and add:

- *Pre-Build Event / Command Line*

  ```
  IF NOT EXIST "bin\*.sln" ( cmake -H"." -B"bin" )
  ```

  or for newer versions of CMake

  ```
  IF NOT EXIST "bin\*.sln" ( 
      cmake -H"." -B"bin" -DCMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM:PATH="$(DevEnvDir)\devenv.exe"
  )
  ```

  Just because I personally don't like it to use `msbuild.exe` (which would be the default).
- *Post-Build Event / Command Line*

  ```
  cmake --build "bin" --config "$(Configuration)"
  ```

**Alternative**

You can also create a root `CMakeLists.txt` importing existing `.vcproj` files via [`include_external_msproject()`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/include_external_msproject.html) commands:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.6)

project(project)

include_external_msproject(${PROJECT_NAME} src/${PROJECT_NAME}.vcxproj)
...
add_subdirectory(dep/library/src library)
```

**Reference**

- [How to know whether the cmake project generation ended with success](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/382531539)
- [MSBuild.exe has stopped cmake error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41173970/msbuild-exe-has-stopped-cmake-error)

Comment: How to "create a Configuration Type / Utility project "  ? In VS2019 under File > New > Project, there are no results for searching "Configuration" or "Utility"