# CMake: How to specify VS2015.3 toolset with VS2017 installed

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, compilation, cmake, visual-studio-2017

I have VS2017 installed, with both VS2017 (v141) and VS2015.3 (v140) toolset installed. I need to generate a solution with CMake and I want CMake to be "fooled" as if VS2015 is installed, so I can build the project with v140 toolset.
I know this question is possibly a duplicate of: 
[How cmake specify "Platform Toolset" for a Visual Studio 2015 project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35549164/how-cmake-specify-platform-toolset-for-a-visual-studio-2015-project)
But the solution it provides doesn't help me.
The error messages are:

```
Selecting Windows SDK version 10.0.14393.0 to target Windows 10.0.15063.
The C compiler identification is unknown
The CXX compiler identification is unknown
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:18 (project):
  No CMAKE_C_COMPILER could be found.
```

I tried installing both VS2017 and VS2015.3 (IDE), but VS2015.3 refused to create even a simple console program.
Is there another way to generate a solution with v140 toolset?
(P.S. Don't tell me that I should generate with v141 toolset first and modify the toolset option in Visual Studio. That makes a big difference. )

Comment: Can you please add the `cmake` command line that produces the error? And could you take please a look at your `CMakeCache.txt` what compiler and nmake paths were used.

Comment: No. I'm using CMake GUI, and I cannot see the actual command from it. I chose "Visual Studio 15 2017 win64" for the generator, and "v140" for -T parameter. I checked CMakeCache,txt but only find out that it cannot find ANY compiler or linker with above configuration.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I've just ran a test and it works for me with the following settings in CMake's GUI (Version 3.10.0 RC4):

[image]

Then I get the following output:

```
The CXX compiler identification is MSVC 19.0.24215.1
Check for working CXX compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0/VC/bin/cl.exe
Check for working CXX compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0/VC/bin/cl.exe -- works
Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
Detecting CXX compile features
Detecting CXX compile features - done
Configuring done
Generating done
```

And if I open the resulting solution it will - as expected - ask me:

[image]

#### Platform Toolset Mapping

From [Marco Foco: Microsoft Visual C++ version Map](http://marcofoco.com/microsoft-visual-c-version-map/):

[image]

### If that don't work ...

First please check the `CMakeError.log` in your binary output directory. The error should give you a lead on what's wrong.

If that's not helping, you can try several things (besides re-installing VS, which I think won't solve the problem):

1. One of the Windows SDKs is not fully/correclty installed; Reinstall from Microsoft's web site
2. Try to give the `cmake-gui` administrative rights
3. Check if there is a GNU toolchain with GCC compiler in your PATH environment.

### References

- [VS 2010 and CMake: 'rc' is not recognized as an internal or external command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42190568/vs-2010-and-cmake-rc-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command)
- [MSBuild.exe has stopped cmake error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41173970/msbuild-exe-has-stopped-cmake-error)
- [Environment variable used by CMake to detect Visual C++ compiler tools for Ninja](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43069632/environment-variable-used-by-cmake-to-detect-visual-c-compiler-tools-for-ninja)

Comment: Well...perhaps reinstalling Visual Studio may solve this problem. I'll try it.

Comment: @AurusHuang If the above is not working, first please check the `CMakeError.log` in your binary output directory. I assume one of the following: 1. One of the Windows SDKs is not fully/correclty installed; Reinstall from Microsoft's web site 2. Try to give the `cmake-gui` administrative rights 3. Check if there is a GNU toolchain with GCC compiler in your `PATH` environment.

Comment: I reinstalled Visual Studio 2017 and upgraded it to latest version. With `v140` typed in CMake, it works.

Comment: Thanks. The strange thing is from console not working but gui working.

Comment: Is there a list of available Tool Set for `XCode` on macOS?